# Numerically stable approach for calculating x in Ax=b

Tags: matrix, stability, inverse-problem

I have an equation $Ax=b$ for which I need to solve for numerous $x$ matrices given $b$. Both $x$ and $b$ are nx1 matrices. Unfortunately, $A$ is a 32x32 matrix and inversion gives highly unstable values. I am wondering what the appropriate algorithm/technique is for obtaining a stable $A$ matrix.

My searches for an alternative calculation approach or way to restore stability to obtain a solution have so far led me nowhere so I would appreciate any input.

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: The $A$ matrix comes from your problem, so I can't help you on how to make that. As far as solving the system, the fully pivoted LU decomposition is numerically stable, but you will still lose precision if $A$ has a large condition number. What have you tried?

Comment: Since you have already tagged this as an inverse problem, presumably you also know the standard regularization techniques (truncated singular value decomposition and Tikhonov regularization) to obtain a stable inversion. Are these not working for you?

Comment: Matrix A is roughly known in this situation so not a problem. To get x, I have only tried LU decomposition to obtain the inverse and Cholesky decomposition to avoid calculating the inverse. I am using the Apache math commons libraries for this. I am not at all familiar with the techniques and am just doing a bunch of reading to try to find an approach. I am not familiar with Tikhonov regularization or truncated singular value decomposition so I will have a read on these to see if I make use of them. Thanks for the ideas so far.

Comment: Right, then I assumed incorrectly. Tikhonov and TSVD are exactly what you need here; I'll give a brief description below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the solution of $Ax=b$ is unstable, the matrix is very ill-conditioned (i.e., has a very large condition number), and (paraphrasing Lanczos) no amount of mathematical trickery can make it stable. The best you can hope for is to solve a *different* problem that is a) stable and b) gives you a solution that is sufficiently close; this is called *regularization*.

For linear ill-conditioned problems, there are two classical approaches:

1. *Tikhonov regularization* replaces $Ax=b$ by the stabilized least-squares problem 
   $$ \min_x \|Ax-b\|^2 + \alpha \|x\|^2$$
   for some regularization parameter $\alpha>0$. The minimizer can of course be computed by solving the normal equations
   $$ (A^TA+\alpha I)x_\alpha = A^Tb.$$
2. *Truncated singular value decomposition* computes the singular value decomposition
   $$ U \Sigma V^T = A,$$
   where the columns of $U$ and $V$ contain the left and right singular vectors, respectively, and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing the singular values (usually in order of descending magnitude). Since $U$ and $V$ are unitary, the inverse of $A$ (if it exists) is given by $A^{-1}=V\Sigma^{-1} U^T$. Ill-conditionedness of $A$ manifests in the existence of very small singular values, such that the corresponding entry in $\Sigma^{-1}$ would be very large, amplifying small perturbations (e.g., due to finite numerical precision). As the name indicates, stability is restored by ignoring these small entries, i.e., replacing $\Sigma^{-1}$ by
   $\Sigma_{\alpha}^{-1}$ where
   $$[\Sigma_{\alpha}^{-1}]_{ii} = \begin{cases} \Sigma_{ii}^{-1} & \text{if } |\Sigma_{ii}| > \alpha \\ 0 &\text{else}
   \end{cases}$$
   and setting 
   $$x_\alpha = V\Sigma_{\alpha}^{-1} U^T b.$$

In both cases, you need to choose $\alpha$ specifically for your problem to get good results. You could start by computing the SVD of a representative $A$ and looking at the singular values to see if there's a clear threshold.

Comment: I am off to try these approaches. This is what I needed. Thanks.